Comparison of biodiversity between two locations with a known maximum number of species
I would like to compare biodiversity at two sites over a three-year period. We have two plots—one urban and the other peripheral. In both plots, 17 species were initially planted, although with slightly different abundances. Over three years, the number of species and their frequencies were recorded once a year. Species that migrated in were regularly removed, so the maximum number of species is known.
Now, for each site, the goal is to describe how biodiversity developed over the three years. Ideally, both sites should be compared.
I was considering using the Shannon Index and Simpson Evenness for this.
Does that make sense?
Can the two sites even be compared if the initial number of individuals wasn’t the same?
What would you recommend in terms of statistical analysis?
Thank you very much!

So long as you have enough individuals in the sample areas to get some statistical significance out of it, I don't see any problems here. You should have done some a priori test design to work this out before setting up the plots.

Thanks for your respond! Unfortunatly i did not do this priori test before. There are at least 9 Individuals per plot and 4 plots per site. Do you think this could be enough?

This sounds like something your supervisor should be handling. You should look up the Shannon Diversity Index and the Simpson Evenness Index and read about their capabilities and limitations.

You could also use a binomial (or quasi/beta-binomial to account for overdispersion) model for this (how many "successes" are there out of 17 "trials") ?

thanks you. i will think about this.
